# Re-entry to the UK after a 10-year ban

Tags: uk, visa-bans

I overstayed my visa in the UK and tried to beat the system by getting an emergency visa for my voluntary exit. After I returned to Nigeria, thinking I was smart, I used forged immigration stamps on my passport and this was discovered by the ECO when I made a fresh application in 2008.

In all honesty, I was desperate to return to the UK and I decided to appeal the decision but it was rejected and I was issued a 10-year ban for forgery and overstaying my visa.

During this period, I have got my act together, got married and have a good job. I have been to other countries including the UAE, the US and South Africa and did not stay beyond 1 month on each trip during the period.

1. What are my chances of getting a tourist visa to the UK by April 2018 when my ban is over?
2. If I apply with my family now, would my past affect their chances?
3. If yes to Q2, is it wise for them to apply alone as I am no longer keen to visit the UK?

Answer (score 8):

You have a history of fraud, overstaying, and deception so you can expect any future application to be checked very carefully. If you are not interested in visiting the UK anyway then it may well be better to let your family visit and you stay at home.

Comment: There's no harm in trying. The OP's actions would no longer be an automatic grounds for refusal. However, his credibility would have been significantly damaged. 10 years is a very long time.

Comment: Is there really no harm in trying? Would it not look better to leave *more* than the ten years to truly prove that the OP has no major interest in getting in as soon as possible, rather than try again *as soon as* the ban is over?

Comment: I see where you are coming from @Philbo. It does makes sense to cool off a bit after the ban since there is no pressing need to be in the U.K.